# Weighted least-squares negative fitted values

Tags: regression, predictive-models, least-squares, weighted-regression

I am running a weighted least-squares regression (where all weights are strictly positive), where my dependent variable is a cross-section of variance values.

Since variance is always positive (>=0), I would expect my fitted values to be positive as well, for them to be meaningful,

$\sigma^2_i = \alpha + \beta * x_i + \epsilon _i$

The problem is that I am getting some negative fitted values:

$\hat{\sigma}^2_i =  \hat{\alpha} + \hat{\beta} * x_i $ for some $i$

Is there any suggestion as to how to constraint the predicted values to be positive?

Thanks!

Comment: You could regress $\log \sigma_i^2$, and then take the exponential of the prediction.

Comment: I am not quite sure how that would solve the issue: you mean use $log\sigma^2_i)$ as my dependent variable, but keep the explanatory variable without log transformation?

Comment: yes, I'll write an answer with more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform your dependent variable $\sigma^2$ with a logarithm and fit the following model

$$\log \sigma_i^2 = \alpha + \beta x_i + \epsilon_i$$

Get an estimate of the variance $\eta^2$ of the residuals as

$$\hat{\eta^2} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N (\log \sigma_i^2 - \alpha - \beta x_i)^2$$

Finally, use the estimator

$$\hat{\sigma_i^2} = \exp\left(\hat{\alpha} + \hat{\beta} x_i + \frac{\hat{\eta^2}}{2}\right)$$

The reason there is a $\frac{1}{2}\hat{\eta^2}$ term is because if $\epsilon$ is normally distributed with mean 0, $e^\epsilon$ has expectation $e^{\eta^2/2}$.

Since $\hat{\sigma_i^2 }$ is an exponential, it will always be positive.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. But how can that extra term be estimated?

Comment: I'll edit the explanation to incorporate that

Comment: Thank you very much. Is this what is called a GLS with log link function? Also, I know the expression of $\hat{\beta}$ in the case of a weighted-least squares, but once I add the log transformation, I don't know how to adjust the \beta expression.

Comment: I'm not sure what it's called. The log transformation doesn't change anything about how you'd go about estimating beta or alpha, it's a linear model, but for the log of the $\sigma^2$

Comment: Can I do this transformation even if this is a WEIGHTED LEAST SQUARES regression, not a simple OLS? If so, how should the above formulas be adjusted to account for the weights?

Comment: Would you please point me to a source where this derivation is done?

Comment: What derivation... I'm not sure what to tell you, this is fairly straightforward... you model the log instead of the value itself... and no it won't be exactly the same model, but you'll get positive values.

Comment: I am not talking about the derivation for log OLS, I am talking about logging the dependent variable for a weighted least squares.

Comment: Ah OK, you wonder if you should adjust the weights. No, there's no particularly principled reason to change the weights. Keep them as is.

Comment: I just re-thought about your method and I have one small doubt about it: For you to introduce the log-transformation in this case,  and derive that final result, you need to assume that $\log{\sigma^2}$ is normally distributed. However, I can not make that assumption here (and this is why I am using weighted-least squares instead of OLS). The only assumption I am making is that the errors have zero mean. Therefore, I am not sure this transformation is valid in this case.

Comment: By definition, the variance is a chi-squared variable.

Comment: If you have more information on the distribution of your variables, you should indicate it. Linear regressions are very common, even when the dependent isn't normally distributed. This is but an approximation.

Also note that not all sample variances follow a chi-square distribution, only those of normal distributions.

Comment: Yes I realize that. In my case, the underlying variable is normal, therefore the variance is approximately a chi-square. Can I still use this transformation, in your opinion? I doubt that though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18745/discussion-between-mayou-and-arthur-b).

Comment: Hi Arthur, I would have a quick follow-up, would you mind jumping back to chat please? Thanks!\

Comment: Hi Arthur, about the taylor expansion you mentioned: in this case let $X = log{\sigma^2}$. Taylor expansion is as follows: $E[f(x)] = f(\mu_x) + f''(\mu_x)/2 * \sigma_x^2$. In this case $f(x) = e^x$. Then the taylor expansion is: $E[e^x] = e^{\mu_x} + e^{\mu_x}/2 * \sigma_x^2$. Which is not what you actually suggested in your answer above. Or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: yes, you need to expend around mu

Comment: I understand, but this is what you get $\hat{\sigma}_i^2 = exp(\hat{\alpha} + \hat{\beta} * x_i) + \frac{1}{2} exp(\hat{\alpha} + \hat{\beta} * x_i) * \hat{\eta}^2$. This does not correspond to what you suggested above.

Comment: You have to account for the dependency of the higher moments on the second moment. Simpler way to look at it: everything is a Gaussian when you approximate log likelihood to the second order.

Comment: One follow-up: what is the advantage of taking log here (log OLS) as opposed to using GLM with log-link function?